# Very long logging time via ssh and GSSAPIAuthentication. Can turning off GSSAPIAuthentication be a security issue?

Tags: centos, security, ssh, fedora

I had a problem with very long logging via ssh to my servers (Fedora 16 and Centos 6). After testing some configuration I discovered that the problem is in enabled GSSAPIAuthentication options. After hashing this GSSAPIAuthentication connecting to ssh is very fast. I am wondering is turning off GSSAPIAuthentication good idea. Is there a good reason to not disabling it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GSSAPIAuthentication is merely a directive that enables an alternative authentication option. Examples of other authentication options would be keyboard-interactive (typing your password) or SSH keys. If you aren't using GSSAPI then there is no downside to disabling it.

Source: http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/sshd_config/